# What db schema to use with one-to-two correspondence in django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I know that `OneToOneField` makes one to one correspondence, and `ForeignKey` makes one-to-many correspondence.

Is there a more efficient way than `ForeignKey` to store one-to-two correspondence?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you want to have two `OneToOneField` fields, the only other way is through `ForeignKey`.

Comment: How OneToOneField behaves in terms of queries. I have big tables, so need to think about efficient queries. Does OneToOneField use join? Maybe there are other solutions not related to mysql?

Comment: How big is a big table?  OneToOne is fairly efficient as it creates indexes so all lookups are index lookups.  OneToOne fields use join when you want them to use joins.

Comment: Table is 7 million rows. Can you show how to use 2 OneToOne Fields? I didn't get.  I'm creating italian vocabulary and in italian language same noun in different genders means different things. So, I want to store word in one table and key to it together with gender in separate table. There are only 2 genders.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with two OneToOneField keys:

```
from django.db import models

class Meaning(models.Model):
    definition = models.TextField(null=True)

class Word(models.Model):
    masculine_meaning = models.OneToOneField(Meaning, null=True, related_name='mword')
    feminine_meaning = models.OneToOneField(Meaning, null=True, related_name='fword')
    pronunciation = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
```

Example based on Spanish (my Italian is peggiore)

```
meaning1 = Meaning()
meaning1.meaning = 'Hand'
meaning1.save()
meaning2 = Meaning()
meaning2.meaning = 'Lever'
meaning2.save()
word1 = Word()
word1.pronunciation = 'braccio'
word1.masculine_meaning = meaning1
word1.feminine_meaning = meaning2
word1.save()
```

Query for hand

```
qs = Meaning.objects.filter(definition='Hand').select_related('mword', 'fword')
for x in qs:
    if x.mword: print x.mword.pronounciation
    if x.fword: print x.fword.pronounciation
```

Comment: For example braccio (masculine) is hand and braccio (feminine) is lever. I don't see how it maps to your models. I want braccio(m) and braccio(f) to be separate instances as there are many languages to translate to and according to your schema I need separate table for every language to translate from italian.

Comment: Yeah, but then you don’t have a one-to-two relationship anymore.  Then you really do want a many to one so that you can go from the meaning to the word in any language.